# Evaluate page with chrome-remote-interface + nwjs (node-webkit)

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, node-webkit

I am having an issue with evaluating a page with chrome-remote-interface + nwjs.

Now if I dont redirect my page to a different URL, then evaluate doesn't throw an error, but when I navigate to a different URL with Page.navigate({ url: URL }) and then after call evalute, I am getting an error saying, that the page is not opened.

Any suggestions?

ISSUE
https://github.com/cyrus-and/chrome-remote-interface/issues/23.